# Get X-robots-tag in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, x-robots-tag

I would like to check if a list of URL doesn't have a `noindex`.
So I check already

`< meta name="robots" >`

with DOM, but I would like to also check the X-robots-tag. Is there an easy way to do it?

The only way I can imagine is a `foreach()` on `get_headers($url)`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `x-robots-tag` but maybe `get_headers($url, 1)` and `empty($var['X-robots-tag')`.. assuming any value means don't crawl (`0` would be valid here there)